# How do you become someone's admirer on 9gag?

Tags: rss, images

The following excerpt was extracted from [the FAQ](http://9gag.com/faq).

> **What are admirers?**
>
> Admirers are people who receive your Fun. If
> someone admires you, they're your admirers – they'll receive your Fun
> in their homepage. If you admire someone, you are their admirer.
>
> **What is admiring?**
>
> Admiring someone on 9GAG means you are subscribing to their Fun, and their Fun will appear on your 9GAG homepage. Your admirer/admiring stats are listed on your profile page.

If I understood it well I can have a page fed with customized content. I've looked everywhere and couldn't find a 'subscribe' button or where in my own page I'd see that. How do I become someone's admirer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the FAQ you cite is out of date with the current features of 9gag. I'm guessing those features (admire, subscribe) aren't considered to be adding value, and so they removed them, but didn't update the FAQ. The features I see are "What's Hot", "Trending" and "Vote"; none of those are in the FAQ...

Speculation:

> The genre of sites such as 9gag, reddit, 4chan and digg ([whose business pretty much failed in a big way](http://www.forbes.com/sites/jeffbercovici/2012/07/12/digg-once-worth-164-million-sold-to-betaworks-for-500k/)) are based on a very dynamic (unstable) business model. This means they constantly change their sites and features, and probably put the updating of the FAQ at the bottom of their priority list.